# Linked List From Flash memory transitioning into Ram

Tags: c, linked-list, embedded

Alright so I am new here so please be easy on me :)

I am currently developing on a uC in C and using linked lists to create structures every time the user wants to create one.  Example:

```
typedef struct {
char*                   dataitem;
struct listelement      *link;
int16_t                 wordSize;
int16_t                 (*libWord)[Q];
char                    gpioValue;
}listelement;

listelement * AddItem (listelement * listpointer, char* name, int16_t size, int16_t wordLength, int16_t (*words)[L][Q]) {
// returns listPointer at the beginning of list
listelement * lp = listpointer;
listelement * listPointerTemp;
char ErrorHandler = NULL;
// are we at the end of the list?
if (listpointer != NULL) {
    // move down to the end of the list
    while (listpointer -> link != NULL)
    listpointer = listpointer -> link;
    listPointerTemp = listpointer;
    listpointer -> link = (struct listelement  *) malloc (sizeof (listelement));
    // on fail end links becomes NULL already above
    if(listpointer -> link != NULL){
        listpointer = listpointer -> link;
        listpointer -> link = NULL;
        listpointer -> wordSize = wordLength;

        listpointer -> dataitem = (char*) malloc ((size + 1)*sizeof(char));
        if(listpointer -> dataitem != NULL){
            for(int i=0; i<size ; i++){
                listpointer -> dataitem[i] = name[i];
            }
            listpointer -> dataitem[size] = NULL;

            listpointer -> libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
            if(listpointer -> libWord != NULL){
                for (int16_t row=0 ; row < wordLength ; row++){
                    for (int col=0 ; col < Q ; col++){
                        listpointer -> libWord[row][col]  = words[0][row][col];
                    }
                }
                ErrorHandler = 1;
            }else{
                free(listpointer->dataitem);
                free(listpointer);
                listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
            }
        }else{
            free(listpointer);
            listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
        }
    }
    if(ErrorHandler == NULL){
        //failure
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
    }
    return lp;
}
else {
    listpointer = (struct listelement  *) malloc (sizeof (listelement));

    if(listpointer != NULL){
        listpointer -> link = NULL;
        listpointer -> wordSize = wordLength;

        listpointer -> dataitem = (char*) malloc (sizeof(name));
        if(listpointer -> dataitem != NULL){
            for(int16_t i=0; i<size ; i++){
                listpointer -> dataitem[i] = name[i];
            }

            listpointer -> libWord =  (int16_t(*)[Q])malloc(wordLength*Q*sizeof(int16_t));
            if(listpointer -> libWord != NULL){
                for (int16_t row=0 ; row < wordLength ; row++){
                    for (int col=0 ; col < Q ; col++){
                        listpointer -> libWord[row][col]  = words[0][row][col];
                    }
                }
                ErrorHandler = 1;
            }else{
                free(listpointer->dataitem);
                free(listpointer);
                listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
            }
        }else{
            free(listpointer);
            listPointerTemp -> link = NULL;
        }
    }
    if(ErrorHandler == NULL){
        //failure
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"Ran out of Memory!  Word not created.\r\n");
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
    }
    return listpointer;
}
}
```

So now I want to add structures already stored in memory using const as such:

```
    // start to include words, then merge into structures for user_interactive to link lists with
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                          TRON
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const int16_t libWord1[10][Q] = {   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},        
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},    };


const char dataitem1[4] = {'T','r','o','n'};

const int16_t wordSize1 = 10, nameSize = 4;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// eventually change NULL to next link in link list
const listelement Tron = { dataitem1, NULL, wordSize1, libWord1, 0x00 };
```

Alright so even if you skip reading all of that, I was just wondering what a good way of somehow create constant structs (do I have to create a new structure format just for const types?) and then link the beginning of the RAM linked lists when user creates first one to the Flash portion of linked lists created on startup?

Let me know if more information is needed.  I tried not to put too much code on here.

Thanks!

So here is the change and the effects:

```
// start to include words, then merge into structures for user_interactive to link lists with
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                          TRON
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const int16_t libWord1[10][Q] = {   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},        
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
                                    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},    };

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                          ON
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const int16_t libWord2[10][Q] = {   {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},        
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                                    {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1},    };

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// eventually change NULL to next link in link list
const listelement* Tron = { "Tron", NULL, 10, libWord1, 0x00 };
// next element links to Tron . . .
const listelement* On = { "On", Tron, 10, libWord2, 0x01 };
// next element links to On . . . and so on . . .

listelement* constLinkInit(void){
    return On;
}
```

I know I didn't do your global array of structs but ignoring that and passing the last struct to this guy in a nother file using a function.

```
listelement *listpointer;

    // initially listpointer is initialized to NULL but now set to end of link list of FLASH
    listpointer = constLinkInit();
```

And the going to print links like I had been doing for user defined structs dynamically (which had worked) fails when pointing to the next link even though the address passed to listpointer (On) is correct.

```
void PrintQueue (listelement * listpointer) {
    usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
    if (listpointer == NULL){
        usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"queue is empty!\r\n");
    }else{
        //usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"               Word List                    \r\n");
        //usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"--------------------------------------------\r\n");
        while (listpointer != NULL) {
            //usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0, listpointer -> dataitem);
            //usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n");
            //writeCOM_int_array(listpointer -> libWord , listpointer -> wordSize);
            listpointer = listpointer -> link;   // <---- FAILS HERE
        }
    }
    usart_write_line(&AVR32_USART0,"\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n");
}
```

When pointing to the next link it goes to the wrong address . . .

Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW: the linked list code is terrible, IMHO. It can be reduced to about 1/3 its size. BTW2: what is this `(*libWord)[Q];` thing? just a fixed size pointer array?

Comment: Yes it is very likely you could write this better than me which is why I am asking you guys, "the experts," :).  It is fixed in columns but varies by rows in the code to put it simply.

Comment: Please note `dataitem1` is  not NUL terminated. Should be : `char dataitem1[] = "Tron";` or `char *dataitem1 = "Tron";` (yes, I kbow, you are passing a *size* argument to, but it looks overly complex.)

Comment: The new code is everything below "Thanks", but yes I agree it was overly complex before I saw how you did it.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add the **intention** of the `->dataitem ` element. What is it supposed to contain, pointers, or actual data ? (IMO its usage conflicts with its definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define Q 5


typedef struct {
 char                    *dataitem;
 struct listelement      *link;
 int16_t                 wordSize;
 int16_t                 (*libWord)[Q];
 char                    gpioValue;
 } listelement;

int16_t zzz[Q] = { 11, 22,33,44,55};

listelement global_array[] =
{{ "Sron", global_array+1, 2, zzz , 0 }
,{ "Tron", global_array+2, 2, zzz , 0 }
,{ "Uron", global_array+3, 2, zzz , 0 }
,{ "Vron", NULL          , 2, zzz , 0 }
};
```

Comment: So I was trying to make const listelement global_array[] in your example but when pointing to the next link it goes to the wrong address . . . thoughts?

Comment: If it is const (or even worse: in ROM) you cannot change the final ->link pointer, so you won't be able to add anything to the list. BTW: you must find a way to distinguish between *fixed* nodes and malloc()ed nodes. Free() will certainly crash your program when given a pointer to a non-dynamic object.

Comment: That is what I thought.  I will post a simplified example of what I mean just trying your code with two words defined as const and exactly what happens in debug mode. . .

Comment: ROM/RAM info is already encoded in the pointers.  You can check the address before calling `free()`.